Coloring column with merged cells
I have a small table with a merged cell. So long as I don't fill the background with some color, the text appears fine. But when I do supply a color, the visible text is truncated with a thin line going through.

How do I color an entire column that has merged cells?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\TableMarks}{\multirow{2}{*}{\centering \textbf{Title}}}
\newcommand{\TableTotal}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\centering \textbf{Total}}}
\newcommand{\TableTM}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\centering \textbf{30}}}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{gray}}c}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|a|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \TableMarks & & A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & \TableTM & \TableTotal  \\ 
    \cline{3-6} 
      &  & & & & & & \\ 
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{8}{l}}[hvlines]
\Block[fill=gray]{2-1}{\textbf{Title}} & \Block{2-1}{} & A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 &
   \Block[fill=lightgray]{2-1}{\textbf{30}} & \Block[fill=lightgray]{2-1}{\textbf{Total}} \\
\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}



You can set the \multirow "in reverse" with a negative rowcount:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\TableMarks}{\multirow{2}{*}{\centering \textbf{Title}}}
\newcommand{\TableTotal}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\centering \textbf{Total}}}
\newcommand{\TableTM}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\centering \textbf{30}}}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{gray}}c}

\begin{tabular}{|a|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \TableMarks & & A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & \TableTM & \TableTotal  \\ 
  \cline{3-6} 
  & & & & & & & \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ *{8}{ | l } | }
  \hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray}                                & & A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & 
    \cellcolor{lightgray} & 
    \cellcolor{lightgray}                                    \\ 
  \cline{3-6} 
  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\bfseries Title} & &    &    &    &    & 
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\bfseries Total} & 
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\bfseries 30}      \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


While I've used \cellcolor{lightgray} for the first column, you can also set/colour it via your defined a-column.

You could also use tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={c*{7}{l}},
        hlines,
        vlines,
        column{1}={gray},
        column{Y,Z}={lightgray},
        cell{1}{1,2,Y,Z}={r=2}{font=\bfseries},
        abovesep=3pt
        }
        Title & & A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & 30 & Total \\ 
        & & & & & & & \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document} 


